# Is there a SaaS for checking uploaded files for viruses?

Tags: webapp-rec

Preferably one that runs in AWS so that checking files in S3 does not use up bandwidth allocation

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [metascan-online.com](http://www.metascan-online.com/)? It has the benefit of multiple engines, however, I don't know if they allow users with persistently large usage.